# FireFox Security Warning using PayPal Pro Hosted Solution

Tags: paypal

With pro hosted solution using Firefox. After paying, I am presented with a blank page that pops a security warning up saying

> Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is
>   to be sent over an unencrypted   connection and could easily be read
>   by a third party. Are you sure you want to continue sending this
>   information?

Once they click ok they return to our non-ssl thank you page. Surely there must be a way around this for a commercial hosted payment solution? It's fine in all other browsers?